# How to fix DNSMismatch?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, hosting

I tried to crawl a project of mine with scrapy and received a warning which worries me. The config seems to be wrong, but everything works as expected. What is the reason for DNSMismatch and how can I fix this?

> WARNING: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname "www.findix.de";
>   VerificationError(errors=[DNSMismatch(mismatched_id=DNS_ID(hostname=b'www.findix.de'))])

Comment: Check the certificate? This post is so vague that I'm not really sure if you can get any other answer.

Comment: The certificate looks fine when checked in google chrome.

Comment: Is your crapwler sending a proper http header? Including a host name? It may be a casde of getting the WRONG certificate becasue of not sending a header. Sending the site header is part of the http standard, btw.,

Answer (score 0):

We can tell that your certificate has

- SANs for `www.findix.de` and `findix.de`,
- chain for intermediate certificates and
- is currently valid.

This certificate would work on any major browser, and that's the only thing you should worry about. Scrapy seems known to have this kind of false errors before and is not something your users would be using, anyway. I woudn't spend too much time trying to fix this, if it works.